# How to find the highest value for a column nested in JSON?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to find the maximum value in a JSON object. This is my data-

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "a", value: 12}
1: {name: "b", value: 28}
2: {name: "c", value: 60}
```

I'd like to get the maximum value, but they're nested. I could do something like this

```
arr = {}    
for (x in jsonObj){
  arr.push(x.value)
}    
d3.max(arr)
```

I was curious if there's a better way of dealing with this situation. My goal is to use d3.max() to find the highest value.

Comment: I'm adding a note that the object is not an array. It is parsed with `d3.json()` and under constructor > name, it says "Object".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = [
    { name: "a", value: 12 },
    { name: "b", value: 28 },
    { name: "c", value: 60 },
]

console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, array.map(function (e) { return e.value; })));
```

Comment: You can use ds =  array.map(function (e) { return e.value; } to make your d3 array and then you can use Math.max(...ds);

Comment: It doesn't work since the object is not an array. It's parsed from a JSON object.

Comment: @Cauder you can turn the object into the array using `Object.values(obj)`

Answer (score 7):

Although the other answers by Hrishi and Nina Scholz are perfectly fine, I would like to mention that the idiomatic way using D3 is to utilize [`d3.max()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#max). You can pass in an accessor function as the second argument which will be invoked for every member of the array and returns the nested value you are interested in.

```js
const data = [
  {name: "a", value: 12},
  {name: "b", value: 28},
  {name: "c", value: 60}
];

const maxValue = d3.max(data, d => d.value);
      // accessor function ---^

console.log(maxValue);  // 60
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```

Comment: S.O. democratic system is broken: this answer of yours, which is very very simple (let's say it's D3 101) has 3 upvotes now (one of them is mine)... However, I've found answers of yours which are way more complex and detailed rotting there, without a single upvote. Go figure...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado That's why we have representative democracies and even those have seen better days...

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array by taking a really small value as start value and get the max of the accumulator and the value.

```js
var array = [{ name: "a", value: 12 }, { name: "b", value: 28 }, { name: "c", value: 60 }],
    max = array.reduce((max, { value }) => Math.max(max, value), -Infinity);

console.log(max);
```